# Overloaded + operator issue being mixed with friend function in other class

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NumDays.h"
#include "Overtime.h"
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

NumDays::NumDays(double hourss)
{

    if(hourss > 0)
    {
        hours = hourss;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Invalid number given.";
        cout << endl << "Hours set to 0." << endl;
        hours = 0.00;
    }

}


NumDays operator + (const NumDays& right)
{
    NumDays temp;

    temp.hours = this->hours + right.hours;
    return temp;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef NUMDAYS_H
#define NUMDAYS_H
#include "Overtime.h"

class Overtime;

class NumDays
{
    friend class Overtime;

    private:
        //double hours = 0.00;
        int days = 0;
        friend void setHoursOT(NumDays&, Overtime&);



    public:
        double hours = 0.00;
        NumDays();
        NumDays(double hourss);
        void getTime();
        double getHours() {return hours;}
        void setHours(double);


        //Overloaded operators
        NumDays operator + (const NumDays&);
        NumDays operator - (const NumDays&);
};


#endif
```

---

```
#ifndef OVERTIME_H
#define OVERTIME_H
#include "NumDays.h"

class NumDays;

class Overtime
{


    private:
        double hours2 = 0.00;
        friend void setHours(NumDays&, Overtime&);



    public:
        Overtime(double hourz);


};
#endif
```

---

Every single time I compile it won't let me finish.  I need to have an overloaded operator but I've had the same problem with trying it on the + operator the - operator and a few others.  It will pop up on line 50 of the implementation file where it says "temp1 = this.hours + rhs.hours;" and say that something is wrong every time.  Also it will sometimes pop up on other variations of doing this saying that a either hours2 in the Overtime piece is private or that hours in the NumDays class is private and won't let me do anything past that.  I have googled since 6 hours ago and found multiple things that ultimately got me nowhere.  The most common solution I had found included  something along the lines of NumDays NumDays::operator+ (const NumDays& lhs, const NumDays& rhs) and adding them that way, but even when I do that it provides me the same error on line 50.  I've tried this->, this. *this. *this-> etc.  No dice.

```
 I've also tried doing it without the Overtime.h/Overtime.cpp and nothing related to that file in there and it ends up saying returned 1 exit status.  Everything works but the overloaded functions and I just can't find where I'm messing up.
```

Comment: "and say that something is wrong every time." -- what does it say?? "Line 50" -- which line 50???

Comment: Where the operators are defined near the bottom of the first snippet of code is where the issue is occuring.  I found a way past that but even then it tells me that hours2 in the Overtime implementation file is private and won't let me continue.  I've experimented with moving it to public and then it only says : undefined reference to `NumDays::NumDays()' and then [Error] Id returned 1 exit status

Comment: Your code contains typos that would prevent compilation; `#include iostream>`, `#include math.h>`. Also, please read about [minimal examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Those aren't actually typos for some reason if I put the "<" and the ">" in the code it made the text disappear.  Rather new here so wasn't sure how to fix it on the fly.

Comment: @DakotaMitchell - Those are typos - just fixed one for you. Fix the others. Also reduce the amount of code to the minimum to demonstrate the problem. Remember - make our job easy as we are doing this for free

Comment: Will do! Sorry, and thank you for the input.  Will work on making the problem explained as easily as possible.

Comment: @DakotaMitchell - Please remove the code that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: There are many good source of information online or in books about operator overloading... For example, **More Effective C++, Item 22** and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators tell you how to implement binary operators using **op=**. For example, you would implement binary + by calling operator +=. Also, it is recommended to define binary operators as free functions for calling symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

`this`is a pointer, not a reference, so you should write `temp1 = this->hours + rhs.hours;` instead of `temp1 = this.hours + rhs.hours;`

That's most likely the error you got at "line 50" as you report.

Moreover:

- your `operator-` is declared as internal but implemented as external.
- your `operator-` implementation makes no sense. `double` has no `hours` attribute...

I recommend that you first work on operator+, make it work and later implemente operator-. Looks like you wrote many code before you first tried to compile, that's a not a good strategy for beginners, compile every time you add a new function, then it will be easier for you to spot out where errors reported by the compiler come from.

Correct implementation will be:

```
NumDays NumDays::operator+(const NumDays& right)
{
    NumDays temp;
    temp.hours = this->hours + right.hours;
    return temp;
}
```

or

```
NumDays NumDays::operator+(const NumDays& right)
{
    double temp;
    temp = this->hours + right.hours;
    return NumDays(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I did compile prior to adding any of the operators and without them everything else worked fine.  You are very right in that I should have only worked on the operator + first before even putting that one in there. Editing for clarity one moment.

Comment: As you declared `operator+`, implementation should be `NumDays NumDays::operator+(const NumDays& right)` not `NumDays operator + (const NumDays& right)`

Comment: For good practice recommandations, you might refer to this article: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators. It is usually recommended to implement binary + operator using operator +=.